# Eclipse + C: unresolved inclusion <ulfius.h>

Tags: c, eclipse, error-handling

I am trying to write a code in C in Eclipse, but I am getting an error while trying to include library ulfius.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
error "Unresolved inclusion" here-> #include <ulfius.h>
```

And when I try to run it I'm getting "Launch failed. Binary not found". Any idea how could I fix this?

Comment: The first error shows that your code will not compile, so there is no binary (executable) to run. -- What kind of project did you select? Did you set up the discovery options in Eclipse correctly?

Comment: I selected a C/C++ Project and not sure what are discovery options?

Comment: There are different C/C++ projects, which one? -- If you have a "C Managed Build": I think it's here: Open your project's properties, C/C++ General, Paths and Symbols: Make sure that you add the path to "ulfius.h" on the "Includes" tab for your C compiler, and the library path and the library on their tabs, too.